# Delete whole CCT deleting Posttype

Tags: php, wordpress

someone please can help me with this function.
When i'm deleting posttype (for example postID 1234) i need to delete all CCT that contains (1234) in customfield.

i'd used this funcion but is not working on deleting post.. maybe CCT different from CPT...

the name of CCT is "chat" and each row have custom_field called "post_id"

```
add_action('before_delete_post', 'delete_all_post_with_same_slug_field_value');
function delete_all_post_with_same_slug_field_value ($postId) {
$post = get_post($postId);
$slug = explode('__trashed', $post->post_name)[0];
$query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => array('chat', 'chat'),
    'meta_query' =>  [[
        'key' => 'post_id',
        'value' =>   $slug
    ]]
]);
foreach ($query->posts as $post) {
  wp_delete_post($post->ID, true);
 }
}
```

Comment: What is a "CCT" supposed to be? Have you verified whether this function executes at all, when you delete a post?

Comment: `$slug = explode('__trashed', $post->post_name)[0];` - not sure why you are doing that, did you not say you wanted to find the CCT by the post _id_?

Comment: Are you trying to get this to run when you _trash_ a post? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/before_delete_post/: _"This hook does not run: For posts that are being marked as trash (unforced). The `wp_trash_post` hook is the functional equivalent, executed just before items are marked as trash."_

Comment: CCT = Jetengine custom content type